# Apache Shiro Realm Configuation

Tags: shiro

I want to use Apache Shiro Security to secure my Java standalone application but I can't find an example about this.

Please help me how I can implement and configure Apache Shiro Standalone App to connect to database and authenticate my app.

Thank You for all.

Comment: I found below configuration for how to connect Apache Shiro to postgres database. Now I don't know how to authenticate users in Main method?You can see here: https://github.com/puppetlabs/razor-server/blob/master/doc/shiro-database.ini

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how far along you are but I recommend reading this documentation on [Programmatic Configuration](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-ProgrammaticConfiguration) of Shiro.  Which will allow you to create a [JdbcRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html), configure it programatically, and then authenticate against it.

Comment: What it doesn't tell you to do is how to assign a datasource programatically, among other things.

Comment: See the linked JavaDoc for the JdbcRealm class.  Specifically the '#setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)' method.

Answer (score 0):

A good start is the [Shiro tutorial](http://shiro.apache.org/tutorial.html) that especially targets standalone applications. For a good reference in creating and connecting your app to a SQL-like server i recommend this [tutorial](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#ConfiguringJDBCRealm). The `datasource`of the PostgreSQL depends on your implementation.

Here is an example for the `shiro.ini` modified for PostgreSQL

```
[main]
# Create and setup user filter.
user = com.example.filter.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter
user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

# Create JDBC realm.
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm

# Configure JDBC realm datasource.
dataSource = org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.URL = jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db
dataSource.user = sa
dataSource.password = sa
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource

# Configure JDBC realm SQL queries.
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM User WHERE username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role FROM UserRoles WHERE userId = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE username = ?)

[urls]
/login.xhtml = user
/app/** = user
```

Comment: `dataSource = org.postgresql.Driver` this won't work since `org.postgresql.Driver` is not a DataSource. `dataSource = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource` would be more correct.